# SSL with default KafkaConsumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Does a default `KafkaConsumer` instance use/support SSL for consuming? I would assume not but I could not yet find a documentation which default properties will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a KafkaConsumer supports SSL. However, by default, all security setting are set to "null".

You will find all configuration in the [Consumer Configs](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs) section of the Kafka documentation.

To be more precise, the default setting of a Kafka Consumer for `security.protocol` is `PLAINTEXT`. Only if you set this on purpose to `SSL` it will enable SSL communication.

Comment: To clarify, if you instantiate a `KafkaConsumer` with an empty `Map` it will not use SSL!?